# FB.login distinguish successful login from cancel if the user connected the app before

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

We have an FB.login call like this:

```
FB.login(function (response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    responseFunction(response.authResponse.userID);
  } else {
    responseFunction(null);
  }
}, { scope: requiredPermissions.concat(optionalPermissions).join(','), return_scopes: true });
```

It properly detects a canceled login if the user didn't connect to the app yet. However, if the user is already connected when they cancel the login, `response` looks like this:

```
authResponse: {
  accessToken: "token",
  data_access_expiration_time: 1560437437,
  expiresIn: 86963,
  reauthorize_required_in: 7776000,
  signedRequest: "bababa",
  userID: "userid"
},
status: "connected"
```

Almost exactly like a successful login response. Luckily, there is also a `grantedScopes` field in the response if the login has been finished properly (because of a `return_scopes` option). However, using it to distinguish between the 2 seems unreliable and hacky.

Is there a better way?

Thank you in advance!

Update:
**Why not use FB.getLoginStatus instead?**

For the context: in my case, FB.login is used to be granted access to the user's pages. It is not used to log them into the app, per se.

I'll be happy if someone points at a mistake in my reasoning. Here it is:

1. Calling FB.login right after FB.getLoginStatus is unreliable due to the modal block in browsers. FB.login needs to be called synchronously within a click handler.
2. FB.getLoginStatus result may and will expire if called before showing the button calling FB.login. A user may and will spend a lot of time on this particular page before clicking the button.

That's why the button click handler immediately calls FB.login. It helps avoid both of the mentioned issues.

Comment: what is your use case for having already connected users through the fb login popup ?

Comment: samb12, I added the answer to your question to the OP

Comment: Not sure what actual problem you are trying to solve here. _“FB.login is used to be granted access to the user's pages”_ - are you talking about their Facebook pages that they manage, or some kind of “user page” within your app?

Comment: 04FS, I mean their Facebook pages. What I tried to say, is that Facebook Login happens once in a very long while for some users, and never for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the presence of `grantedScopes` in response as an indicator of a complete login.